# Canonical basis of the invariant part of $O_q(\mathfrak g)^{\otimes N}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups, canonical-bases

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a semi-simple Lie algebra (We can assume $\mathfrak g=sl(n)$ for simplicity) and let $O_q(\mathfrak g)$ be the corresponding quantum algebra of functions. Then $O_q(\mathfrak g)^{\otimes N}$ is a left $O_q(\mathfrak g)$-comodule or, dually, a right $U_q(\mathfrak g)$-module.
Let $V_N=(O_q(\mathfrak g)^{\otimes N})^{U_q(\mathfrak g)}$ be its subspace invariant under the $U_q(\mathfrak g)$-action.

Did someone work out its Lusztig canonical basis?

Also, since  Lusztig canonical bases are complicated, I wonder if other "nice" bases of it were studied perhaps?